# Prove that the following sum converges: $ S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln(n)+1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Prove that the following sum converges:
> $$
> S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln(n)+1}
> $$

I tried the following approach:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1)\ \ S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\cdot\cos\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(n)+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n\cdot\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(n)+1}\\\\
&(2)\ \ \exists N:\forall n\geq N\ \ \cos\frac{1}{n}\sim 1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \sin\frac{1}{n}\sim \frac{1}{n}\\\\
&(3)\ \ \text{Therefore,}\ \ S = const + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n}{\ln(n)+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n}{2n^2(\ln(n)+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n}{n(\ln(n)+1)}
\end{aligned}
$$

And then I can apply Dirichlet's test to the $3$ sums above and say that all of them are convergent. Therefore, the initial sum $S$ is also convergent. Am I correct?

Comment: I would say this is correct.